# How to make a child div appear above a parent div which has 'overflow' defined?

Tags: css

I've got a modal style div with a 'close button' in the top right hand corner.

[image]

The 'close button' div (`absolute`) appears above its parent div (`fixed`).

This works fine when the parent div has no `overflow` property defined.

When `overflow` is defined in the parent div, however, the close button gets clipped and won't appear above the parent div no matter what absolute / relative / z-index tinkering I do to the parent and child divs.

Is there anyway to get a child div to appear above a parent div which has `overflow` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this and got the desired result:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child_close"></div>
  <div id="child_scrollable_content">
    <p>Put in your scrollable content here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
  position:fixed;
}

#child_close {
  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
  right:-15px;
}

#child_scrollable_content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```